# How do I cite programming manuals and software user guides in IEEE

Tags: citation-style, ieee

I have seen posts on citing documents, but none of them have specified IEEE format in particular. So here is my question. How do I cite technical reference manuals and software user guides in the IEEE format for references?

Comment: Which IEEE journal or conference are you writing this paper for? That venue's site should have instructions on details beyond simply using the IEEE citation style in LaTeX.

Comment: I am writing my Masters thesis

Comment: I would talk to your school then. They will have further information, but I doubt they care too much one way or the other as long as it looks presentable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [IEEE Style guide](https://www.ieee.org/documents/style_manual.pdf) gives the following format for citing **reports**:

> The general form for citing technical reports is to place the name and location of the company or institution after the
>   author and title and to give the report number and date at the end of the reference.
>   Basic Format:
>
> [1] J. K. Author, “Title of report,” Abbrev. Name of Co., City of Co., Abbrev. State, Country, Rep. xxx, year

For **handbooks**:

> [1] Name of Manual/Handbook, x ed., Abbrev. Name of Co., City of Co., Abbrev. State, year, pp. xx-xx.

And **online sources**:

> [1] J. K. Author. (year, month day). Title (edition) [Type of medium]. Available: http://www.(URL)

For example:

> [1] J. Jones. (1991, May 10). Networks (2nd ed.) [Online]. Available: http://www.atm.com

Examples for **manuals/software**:

> [1] L. Breimann. (2003). Manual on Setting Up, Using, and Understanding Random Forests v4.0. [Online].
>   Available: http://oz.berkeley.edu/users/breiman/Using_random_forests_v4.0.pdf, Accessed on: Apr. 16,
>   2014.
>
> [2] M. Kuhn. The Caret Package. (2012) [Online]. Available: http://cranr-project.org/web/packages/caret/caret.pdf

---

Side note: [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/900254/494151) comments that in BibLatex you can use `@software` to generate the correctly formed citation. I'm not sure however if this is supported by the IEEE style templates.